# what is "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in

Tags: stanford-nlp

While installing the new stanfordnlp package on my anaconda prompt i get this error message in red : 
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0vubj778\torch\

what can i do to fix it ?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: i use python 3.6.4

Comment: I would recommend upgrading to Python >= 3.6.8 or Python > 3.7.1 ... unfortunately there are some issues with earlier Python versions.

Comment: i upgraded to 3.7.2 , but same problem occur!!

Answer (score 0):

Same happened in my windows8.1 and python3.7.2 situation.
Did you try install [PyTorch](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pytorch)?
I was able to solve this problem with this way.